# Unable to get all queue names for your WebSphare MQ environment using IBM .Net API

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

How do you get all available queue names from client side, of your MQ environment using the IBM MQ lib for .Net (IBM.WMQ), Version 8.0?
I have written a fine .Net application for reading and sending data to MQ [(similar founds at code project)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37807/How-to-Setup-a-Websphere-MQ-with-C-NET-GUI-to-Put?msg=5241806#xx5241806xx).

Do anyone know if it is possible/how to get all available queue names from the IBM.WMQ .NET lib dynamically as you do when using tool IBM test tool RfhUtil.exe or as you can do with [runmqsc DISPLAY QUEUE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086270_.htm) command from IBM .Net lib?

I have tried to brows the [API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111270_.htm?lang=en), [Reference manual](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/docs/V8.0/PDFs/wmq80.reference.pdf) and [IBM programming guide](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/docs/V8.0/PDFs/wmq80.develop.pdf) without success.

Answer (score 2):

There is certain level of PCF support in MQ .NET but it is undocumented. Here is a sample code to display queue names in queue manager.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using IBM.WMQ;
using IBM.WMQ.PCF;

namespace PCFNET
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InquireQueue();
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Display list of queue names and queue depth for each queue
    /// </summary>
    public static void InquireQueue()
    {
        PCFMessageAgent messageAgent = null;
        try
        {
            // Create bindings connection to queue manager
            messageAgent = new PCFMessageAgent("DEMOQMGR");

            // Build Inquire command to query queue name
            PCFMessage reqeuestMessage = new PCFMessage(MQC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q);
            reqeuestMessage.AddParameter(MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*");

            // Send request and receive response
            PCFMessage[] pcfResponse = messageAgent.Send(reqeuestMessage);

            // Process and print response.
            int pcfResponseLen = pcfResponse.Length;
            for (int pcfResponseIdx = 0; pcfResponseIdx < pcfResponseLen; pcfResponseIdx++)
            {
                try
                {
                    String qName = pcfResponse[pcfResponseIdx].GetStringParameterValue(MQC.MQCA_Q_NAME);
                    int qDepth = pcfResponse[pcfResponseIdx].GetIntParameterValue(MQC.MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH);
                    Console.WriteLine("QName: " + qName + "  Depth: " + qDepth);
                }
                catch (PCFException pcfex)
                {
                    //Ignore exception and get the next response
                }
            }
        }
        catch (PCFException pcfEx)
        {
            Console.Write(pcfEx);
        }
        catch (MQException ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (messageAgent != null)
                messageAgent.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I get QueueNameException (2058) Error when calling InquireQueue() method. I have tried to do this when an active session (to an other queue) is established and also directly after the MqQueueManager object is created with valid connection data. I get the same error in booth cases. Exception thrown: 'IBM.WMQ.MQException' in amqmdnet.dll, CompCode: 2, Reason: 2058 when calling InquireQueue() metod. Since I have a connection established I know that the rights to the MQ is correct. I can not see that QueueManager name is involved with in the InquireQueue() method as it is in the MQQueueManager.

Comment: Did you forgot this in your example?

Comment: The example connects to a local queue manager DEMOQMGR as you can see the name is passed to constructor of PCFMessageAgent class. Reason code 2058 means queue manager name error. Are you connecting to a local queue manager or a remote queue manager. If remote queue manager then you need create an instance of MQQueueManager class with client connection by providing channel name, host and poet number.

Answer (score 0):

There are `PCFMessageAgent` classes in Java, and I can see some seem to refer to equivalent classes in the .NET API.

It's possible to construct the PCF message yourself, as long as you have rights to access `SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE`.

You also need to create reply queues dynamically based on `SYSTEM.COMMAND.REPLY.MODEL` or `SYSTEM.MQSC.REPLY.QUEUE`.